# How can I use the chat full transcript?

Tags: support, chat, search

I had a few interesting chats years ago, and I remember some dates. I tried to trace them, but the full transcript can be scrolled back only one day at a time.

Is there a reasonable way to read the chat transcript of, say, Jan 31 2018?

Answer (score 7):

There is no functionality for this exposed in the UI, but it's pretty easy to do by writing the URL manually. The current URL pattern for chat transcripts is
`https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/<room-number>/<year>/<month>/<day>`, so for example the URL for the h-bar transcript from Jan 31 2018 would be https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/71/2018/1/31.